# Can anyone know how to convert UDID to UUID(40digit to 32digit)

Tags: iphone, ios

How to convert UDID to UUID(40 digit to 32 digit) in following format using ObjectiveC?

```
[0C50D390-DC8E-436B-8AD0-A36D1B304B18]
[8-4-4-4-12]
```

Comment: And why do you want so ? May be your question is different from your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert??? No, you can't convert your UDID to UUID. Apple has removed UDID from programming side. From 1st May 2013, Apple has started rejecting apps which access UniqueIdentifier.

Instead you can create UUID from code which will give you identifier in `[8-4-4-4-12]` format. To generate UUID you can use [CFUUID class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate) like below:

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef);
CFRelease(uuidRef);

NSLog(@"%@",uuidString);
```

Then, please save the `uuidString` in [UserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or in db, because you can not generate the same `uuidString` again.

Comment: and save the above CFUUID value in keychain (as it will be different each time), so even when app is deleted and reinstalled - you can parse from keychain (if it's not there - create, as it will be 1st app launch on device), so now it will be the same and will looks more like UDID (just until clean ios reinstall)

Answer (score 0):

As you know that apple is deprecated UDID in iOS 5, But there is nice approach to generate 32 digit hash value using MD5 algorithm. For this need to provide Wifi-Mac address then MD5 will convert into 32 digit hash value.Using this if you reinstall the application also the UDID will not change.

Note: Apple is not going to accept the Wifi-Mac address in feature(iOS7). Once iOS 7 came to the picture you can not access Wifi-Mac address. Even if you access into your application apple will simply reject your App.

Comment: Using CFUUID class the udid is changing if you reinstall the app in device.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some alternative as follows,

If someone stumble upon to this question, when searching for an alternative. I have followed this approach in `IDManager` class,
This is a collection from different solutions. KeyChainUtil is a wrapper to read from keychain. 
You can also use the `hashed MAC address` as a kind of unique ID.

```
/*  Apple confirmed this bug in their system in response to a Technical Support Incident 
request. They said that identifierForVendor and advertisingIdentifier sometimes 
returning all zeros can be seen both in development builds and apps downloaded over the 
air from the App Store. They have no work around and can't say when the problem will be fixed. */

#define kBuggyASIID             @"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

+ (NSString *) getUniqueID {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        NSString * asiID = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
        if ([asiID compare:kBuggyASIID] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSLog(@"Error: This device return buggy advertisingIdentifier.");
            return [IDManager getUniqueUUID];
        } else {
            return asiID;
        }

    } else {
        return [IDManager getUniqueUUID];
    }
}


+ (NSString *) getUniqueUUID {
    NSError * error;
    NSString * uuid = [KeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:kBuyassUser andServiceName:kIdOgBetilngService error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error geting unique UUID for this device! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!uuid) {
        DLog(@"No UUID found. Creating a new one.");
        uuid = [IDManager GetUUID];
        uuid = [Util md5String:uuid];
        [KeychainUtils storeUsername:USER_NAME andPassword:uuid forServiceName:SERVICE_NAME updateExisting:YES error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error getting unique UUID for this device! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return nil;
        }
    }
    return uuid;
}

/* NSUUID is after iOS 6. */
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}

#pragma mark - MAC address
// Return the local MAC addy
// Courtesy of FreeBSD hackers email list
// Last fallback for unique identifier
+ (NSString *) getMACAddress
{
    int                 mib[6];
    size_t              len;
    char                *buf;
    unsigned char       *ptr;
    struct if_msghdr    *ifm;
    struct sockaddr_dl  *sdl;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = AF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_LINK;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;

    if ((mib[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) {
        printf("Error: if_nametoindex error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 1\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((buf = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Memory allocation error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Error: sysctl, take 2\n");
        free(buf); // Thanks, Remy "Psy" Demerest
        return NULL;
    }

    ifm = (struct if_msghdr *)buf;
    sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(ifm + 1);
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR(sdl);
    NSString *outstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)];

    free(buf);
    return outstring;
}

+ (NSString *) getHashedMACAddress
{
    NSString * mac = [IDManager getMACAddress];
    return [Util md5String:mac];
}

+ (NSString *)md5String:(NSString *)plainText
{
    if(plainText == nil || [plainText length] == 0)
        return nil;

    const char *value = [plainText UTF8String];
    unsigned char outputBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(value, strlen(value), outputBuffer);

    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(NSInteger count = 0; count < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; count++){
        [outputString appendFormat:@"%02x",outputBuffer[count]];
    }
    NSString * retString = [NSString stringWithString:outputString];
    [outputString release];
    return retString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot convert a UDID in to UUID at all. this is not doable and restricted from Apple.
2. You can create your own UUDI or generate it by writing a small code in to your Application.

To create our own unique identifier, we use the Core Foundation function CFUUIDCreate(). It returns a reference to an opaque type CFUUIDRef, which we can convert into a string with the CFUUIDCreateString function.

It is good practice to wrap these calls in a small NSString category so that we can reuse them easily (UUIDs come in handy in many cases, for example if you need to generate unique filenames):

```
@interface NSString (UUID)

+ (NSString *)uuid;

@end


@implementation NSString (UUID)

+ (NSString *)uuid
{
    NSString *uuidString = nil;
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    if (uuid) {
        uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
        CFRelease(uuid);
    }
    return [uuidString autorelease];
}

@end
```

Now, in our code, we generate a fresh UUID on the first launch of our app and store it to the user defaults database:

```
  #define UUID_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY @"UUID"

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:UUID_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY] == nil) {
            [defaults setObject:[NSString uuid] forKey:UUID_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

    ...
```

Hope this will help and clarify your doubts about UUID. All the best!

Comment: It would have been courteous to point out that this is taken from [Ole Begemann's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116862/ole-begemann) blog: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/how-to-replace-the-udid/

Comment: Yeah true. for more details the below url can be read: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/how-to-replace-the-udid/